# Airflow DAG : Customized Email on any of the Task failure

Tags: airflow

Is there any option Customize email and send on any task failure in the DAG. There is an option like 'email_on_failure': True but this doesn't provide an option to Dynamically add content to email Subject or Body.

My DAG will look like below

```
import airflow

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import HttpSensor
import json
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import Variable

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'email': ['test@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'max_active_runs':10
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='TEST_DAG', default_args=args, schedule_interval='@once')

new_cluster = {
    'spark_version': '4.0.x-scala2.11',
    'node_type_id': 'Standard_D16s_v3',
    'num_workers': 3,
    'spark_conf':{
        'spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName':'org.postgresql.Driver',
        .....
    },
    'custom_tags':{
        'ApplicationName':'TEST',
        .....
    }
}

t1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
  task_id='t1',
  dag=dag,
  new_cluster=new_cluster,
  ......
)

t2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='t2',
    method='POST',
    ........    
)

t2.set_upstream(t1)

t3 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='t3',
    method='POST',
   .....
 )

t3.set_upstream(t2)

send_mail = EmailOperator (
    dag=dag,
    task_id="send_mail",
    to=["test@gmail.com"],
    subject=" Success",
    html_content='<h3>Success</h3>')

send_mail.set_upstream(t3)
```

Success case send_mail task will send customized email to specified email id.

But in case any task failure , I want to customized email and send to specified email id. But this is not happening and on failure case ,email send with default subject and body

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you make changes to the airflow.cfg to the smtp configurations or did you leave them as default. I mean did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed it with the help of Airflow TriggerRule, Sample DAG given below :-

```
import airflow

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import HttpSensor
import json
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'email': ['test@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'max_active_runs':10
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='TEST_DAG', default_args=args, schedule_interval='@once')

new_cluster = {
    'spark_version': '4.0.x-scala2.11',
    'node_type_id': 'Standard_D16s_v3',
    'num_workers': 3,
    'spark_conf':{
        'spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName':'org.postgresql.Driver',
        .....
    },
    'custom_tags':{
        'ApplicationName':'TEST',
        .....
    }
}

t1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
  task_id='t1',
  dag=dag,
  new_cluster=new_cluster,
  ......
)

t2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='t2',
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
    method='POST',
    ........    
)

t2.set_upstream(t1)

t3 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='t3',
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
    method='POST',
   .....
 )

t3.set_upstream(t2)

AllTaskSuccess = EmailOperator (
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    task_id="AllTaskSuccess",
    to=["test@gmail.com"],
    subject="All Task completed successfully",
    html_content='<h3>All Task completed successfully" </h3>')

AllTaskSuccess.set_upstream([t1, t2,t3])

t1Failed = EmailOperator (
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    task_id="t1Failed",
    to=["test@gmail.com"],
    subject="T1 Failed",
    html_content='<h3>T1 Failed</h3>')

t1Failed.set_upstream([t1])

t2Failed = EmailOperator (
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    task_id="t2Failed",
    to=["test@gmail.com"],
    subject="T2 Failed",
    html_content='<h3>T2 Failed</h3>')

t2Failed.set_upstream([t2])

t3Failed = EmailOperator (
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    task_id="t3Failed",
    to=["test@gmail.com"],
    subject="T3 Failed",
    html_content='<h3>T3 Failed</h3>')

t3Failed.set_upstream([t3])
```

**Trigger Rules**

Though the normal workflow behavior is to trigger tasks when all their directly upstream tasks have succeeded, Airflow allows for more complex dependency settings.

All operators have a trigger_rule argument which defines the rule by which the generated task get triggered. The default value for trigger_rule is all_success and can be defined as “trigger this task when all directly upstream tasks have succeeded”. All other rules described here are based on direct parent tasks and are values that can be passed to any operator while creating tasks:

all_success: (default) all parents have succeeded

all_failed: all parents are in a failed or upstream_failed state

all_done: all parents are done with their execution

one_failed: fires as soon as at least one parent has failed, it does not wait for all parents to be done

one_success: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does not wait for all parents to be done

dummy: dependencies are just for show, trigger at will

Reference : https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html

Comment: I would not recommend going this way.

Answer (score 13):

I'm using `on_failure_callback` for this. Please note that it will get triggered for *every* failed task in a DAG.

```
def report_failure(context):
    # include this check if you only want to get one email per DAG
    if(task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=None, dag_id=dag_id, key=dag_id) == True):
        logging.info("Other failing task has been notified.")
    send_email = EmailOperator(...)
    send_email.execute(context)

'''

dag = DAG(
    ...,
    default_args={
        ...,
        "on_failure_callback": report_failure
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful .But in my case I wanted to know which task is failed and in the email content , task description should be included . I managed it with the help of  Airflow TriggerRule .

Comment: Airflow will pass task information to `on_failure_callback` as part of context.

Comment: that if condition is not working for me, the task emails get sent though. Any update on that if statement to send only ONE email per task?

Answer (score 1):

Currently using Airflow 1.10.1 :

Custom email option seems to be configurable in the airflow.cfg under "email" section using jinja templates like below :

```
[email]

email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp


subject_template = /path/to/my_subject_template_file


html_content_template = /path/to/my_html_content_template_file
```

Customised message can be created by making use of task-instance information in the html_content_template which is in-turn a jinja template

More details can be found at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/email-config.html

Comment: What should be the content of 'my_subject_template_file' and 'my_html_content_template_file' and the format of them?

Comment: HTML format . Example mentioned in the link  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/email-config.html 


Try {{try_number}} out of {{max_tries + 1}}<br>
Exception:<br>{{exception_html}}<br>
Log: <a href="{{ti.log_url}}">Link</a><br>
Host: {{ti.hostname}}<br>
Mark success: <a href="{{ti.mark_success_url}}">Link</a><br>