# Send an email with attached csv files using apache airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have to send 4 csv files using airflow. The files have been generated using another airflow dag. I want to set the 'subject_template' and the 'html_content_template' but not sure about the content and format.

Step 1: Importing Modules

```
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator 
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator

local_tz = pendulum.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
```

Step 2: Initiating the default_args

```
default_args = {
   'owner' : 'analytics_dwbi',
   'start_date': datetime(2023, 12,4, tzinfo= local_tz),
   'email': ['analytics_dwbi@mjunction.in'],
   'email_on_failure': False,
   'email_on_retry': False,
}
```

Step 3: Creating DAG Object

```
with DAG( 
    dag_id = 'email_weekly_reports',
    default_args = default_args,
    start_date = days_ago(1),
    schedule = '@once',
    template_searchpath = ['/home/dashadmin/Reportsfrom_MySQL_Weekly/']
) as dag:
```

Step 4: Creating task

```
email_task = EmailOperator(task_id='email',
        to='amrapalli.karan@mjunction.in',
        subject='Weekly Reports',
        html_content="HTML content",
        files=['/home/dashadmin/Reportsfrom_MySQL_Weekly/KPI_Report1.csv','/home/dashadmin/Reportsfrom_MySQL_Weekly/KPI_Report2.csv','/home/dashadmin/Reportsfrom_MySQL_Weekly/KPI_Report3.csv','/home/dashadmin/Reportsfrom_MySQL_Weekly/KPI_Report4.csv'],
    )
```

Step 5: Setting up dependencies

```
email_task
```

I have searched for several examples

1. [Airflow DAG : Customized Email on any of the Task failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726248/airflow-dag-customized-email-on-any-of-the-task-failure/63502689#63502689)
2. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html
   I have used the 'html_content_template' example from the link above but its not working.
3. [How to setup Airflow custom email template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313642/how-to-setup-airflow-custom-email-template)
4. https://marclamberti.com/blog/templates-macros-apache-airflow/
5. https://atufashireen.medium.com/creating-templates-with-jinja-in-python-3ff3b87d6740
   and many others

Answer (score 0):

There are no separate "_template" fields, but some of the arguments in Airflow operators are configured to be "templateable". In the case of EmailOperator, those are `to`, `subject`, `html_content`, and `files` ([link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/email/index.html#airflow.operators.email.EmailOperator.template_fields)).

"Templateable" means you can apply templating, which means you can insert "placeholder" code which is evaluated at runtime. For example:

```py
EmailOperator(
    ...,
    subject='Weekly Reports {{ ds }}',
)
```

This will render at runtime to e.g. "Weekly Reports 2023-12-07".

The double curly braces `{{ }}` indicate a template to render at runtime, and the value `ds` is one of the variables available at runtime, see the full list here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the html_content_template and subject_template : 
    subject_template = "Airflow Email Example - {{ ds_nodash }}"                         
    html_content = """
    <html><body><h3>Hello,</h3> <p>This is a sample email sent using Airflow.</p></body></html>
"""

Comment: But now its displaying Broken DAGs